# WinRT Class Library, MVVM and use of Behaviors

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

i'm trying to attach a custom behavior to a ContentControl embedded in a WinRT Class Library.

I have added references to Behavior SDK on library project and on caller project.

My xaml files are loaded via XamlParser.

The xaml file :

```
<Page ...
xmlns:Interactivity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity;assembly=Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" ...>

[...]

<ContentControl ...>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ContentControl>
```

this seems of from code editor, and autocomplete works, but at runtime when i load this xaml via :

```
return XamlReader.Load(xamlPage) as FrameworkElement;
```

I got a ParseException : The attachable property 'Behaviors' was not found in type 'Interaction'.

Xaml reader does not seems to find the property. 
Did i forget something ? Do you have an idea of the problem ?

Thank you,

Comment: Might try `clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity` instead. Oh and I don't think you need to actually include the `<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>` part, just del it.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. In WinRT / Windows 8.1, System.Windows.Interactivity seems to be unacessible. We have to use the Behavior SDK contained in Microsoft.Xaml.interactivity (this DLL are added to references of project by adding "Behviors SDK (XAML)" to extensions of project in VS).



And i need to inclue <Interactivity...> to specify my custom behavior on my component. My code is not full, I deleted the content of this tag, because the tag himshelf is not working, but if it was working it will be useful by his content :)